# Java.lang.NullPointerException while doing if statement

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to use an if statement to `HashMap`, but when I try to run it on a device it crashes.

Here's my code

```
    ImageView promoIcon = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.icon_promo);

    DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(this);

    List <AllItem> allItems = new ArrayList<AllItem>();

    allItems = db.getAllAccommodations();

    for(AllItem cn : allItems) {    

        String promotion = cn.getPromotion();
        if (promotion.equals("1"))
        {
            promoIcon.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        HashMap<String, String> all_Items = new HashMap<String, String>();

        all_Items.put(TAG_PROMOTION,promotion);

        accommodationlist.add(all_Items);


    }
```

Here's my logcat

```
09-09 15:13:37.364: E/AndroidRuntime(18292): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-09 15:13:37.364: E/AndroidRuntime(18292): Process: com.indomultimedia.hellobali, PID: 18292
09-09 15:13:37.364: E/AndroidRuntime(18292): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.indomultimedia.hellobali/com.indomultimedia.hellobali.Accommodation}: java.lang.NullPointerException
09-09 15:13:37.364: E/AndroidRuntime(18292):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2292)
09-09 15:13:37.364: E/AndroidRuntime(18292):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2350)
09-09 15:13:37.364: E/AndroidRuntime(18292):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:163)
09-09 15:13:37.364: E/AndroidRuntime(18292):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1257)
09-09 15:13:37.364: E/AndroidRuntime(18292):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
09-09 15:13:37.364: E/AndroidRuntime(18292):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
09-09 15:13:37.364: E/AndroidRuntime(18292):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5335)
09-09 15:13:37.364: E/AndroidRuntime(18292):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-09 15:13:37.364: E/AndroidRuntime(18292):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
09-09 15:13:37.364: E/AndroidRuntime(18292):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1265)
09-09 15:13:37.364: E/AndroidRuntime(18292):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081)
09-09 15:13:37.364: E/AndroidRuntime(18292):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-09 15:13:37.364: E/AndroidRuntime(18292): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
09-09 15:13:37.364: E/AndroidRuntime(18292):    at com.indomultimedia.hellobali.Accommodation.onCreate(Accommodation.java:296)
09-09 15:13:37.364: E/AndroidRuntime(18292):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5389)
09-09 15:13:37.364: E/AndroidRuntime(18292):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
09-09 15:13:37.364: E/AndroidRuntime(18292):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2256)
09-09 15:13:37.364: E/AndroidRuntime(18292):    ... 11 more
```

I don't really know why there's an error. Can anyone help me fix it?

Comment: Whats on line 296 in Accomodation class?

Comment: At what line does it stop?

Comment: One of the objects you're using is `null`. Did you debug to see where the error occurs? If not: why not? And which of the lines you quoted is line 296?

Comment: A quick spin in an IDE with line numbers turned on and a break point added at line 296 will sort this out.

Comment: line 296 is this code `promoIcon.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);`

Comment: Please show some more code. Like `setContentView` and xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your comment to the question, the following line returns `null`:

```
 ImageView promoIcon = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.icon_promo);
```

This means that `findViewById` did not find the view you're looking for, so trying to access the object in this line

```
 promoIcon.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

fails, as `promoIcon == null` and you can not call any methods on `null`. That's exactly what the exception message says: One of the object variables you were trying to use was not initialized. Your job is to by debugging find out which one :-)